# Помогите с передачей картинки в ViewPager

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

При передаче картинки, идет смещение на одну статью!!(Тоесть когда я нажимаю на картинку которая мне нужна, то открывается та которая на сл.статье))

Передаю так:

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private int mShowStyle;
        VKPostArray obj;
        VKApiPost p;
        VKApiPhoto vkPhoto;
        ArrayList<String> imgUrls1;
        VKApiUser mainUser;
        ArrayList<String> al;
        Collection l;
        Context ctx;
        Picasso picasso;

        public PostAdapter(Context context, VKPostArray posts, VKApiUser user, int showStyle) {
            super();
            this.obj = posts;
            this.mainUser = user;
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.mShowStyle = showStyle;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, int position) {

            p = obj.get(position);

            holder.textPost.setText(p.text);
            holder.textlikePost.setText(" " + p.likes_count);
            holder.textrepostPost.setText(" " + p.reposts_count);

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
            holder.textDatePost.setText(format.format(new java.util.Date(p.date * 1000)));

            VKAttachments att = new VKAttachments();
            att = p.attachments;

            int i;
            imgUrls1 = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                for (i = 0; i <= att.size(); i++) {
                    vkPhoto = (VKApiPhoto) att.get(i);
                    imgUrls1.add(vkPhoto.photo_604);
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                holder.mNglContent.setImagesData(imgUrls1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return obj.size();
        }

        @Override
        public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            if (mShowStyle == NineGridImageView.STYLE_FILL) {

                return new PostViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall, parent, false));
            } else {
                return new PostViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall, parent, false));
            }}

        public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            CardView cv;
            TextView textPost, news_name, textDatePost, textrepostPost, textlikePost;
            ImageView like, repost ;
            NineGridImageView mNglContent;

            private NineGridImageViewAdapter<String> mAdapter = new NineGridImageViewAdapter<String>() {
                @Override
                protected void onDisplayImage(Context context, ImageView imageView, String s) {
                    Picasso.with(context).load(s).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_ab_app).into(imageView);
                }

                @Override
                protected ImageView generateImageView(Context context) {
                    return super.generateImageView(context);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onItemImageClick(Context context, int position, List<String> list) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullPhoto.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_BITMAP, imgUrls1);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            };

            public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_wall);

                news_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_name);
                textDatePost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatePost);
                textPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPost);

                textlikePost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_likes_count);
                textrepostPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_reposts_count);
                like = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_like);
                repost = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_repost);

                mNglContent = (NineGridImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ngl_images);
                mNglContent.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        }
```

Принимаю так:

```
 ar1 = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList(Constants.BUNDLE_BITMAP);
```

по дебаггеру, она уже уходит из onItemImageClick со смещением

```
@Override
                protected void onItemImageClick(Context context, int position, List<String> list) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullPhoto.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_BITMAP, imgUrls1);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            };
```

Может кто знает как исправить????

Comment: я вам даже скажу, что если вы пролистаете в самый конец, а потом начнете листать обратно, то она пойдет уже сосмещением назад. Все потому, что вы используете переменную imgUrls1,  в которую сохраняются данные последнего отрендеренного элемента списка, а не того, ка который вы кликаете.

Comment: А какую переменную надо использовать? или создать?